# ng new Angular keeps on failing

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am currently trying to create a new Angular Project using `ng new <project name>`.

Unfortunately the installation keeps on failing with the following message:
`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...GjDuJR1CRkujHFCGXqGwM'`

In all other cases of this problem, the solution was to use `npm cache clear -f`.
This however did not work in my case.

Other solutions were to remove the node_modules folder but that does not help either, as we have to delete the project to restart anyway.

Here are the versions I am using
npm 6.14.4
Node 12.16.2
Angular CLI 9.1.3

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be a cache issue. Try `npm cache clean --force`, `npm install` and run `ng new <project>` again.

Comment: @MichaelD thank you for the help. 
The trick was to call `npm install` from inside the folder of the failed project and restart it multiple times until it didn't crash.